# Gremlin groupCount, order and limit

Tags: node.js, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am currently using gremlin with aws neptune cluster and using nodejs for development. I have find friends with same interest and order by mutual interest count. I need to limit results to top 2.

```
const res = await g.V().has('user', 'name', 'Waruna').as('u')
    .out('like').in_('like')
    .where(P.neq('u'))
    .valueMap()
    .by(gremlin.process.statics.unfold())
    .groupCount()
    .order(gremlin.process.scope.local)
    .by(gremlin.process.column.values, gremlin.process.order.desc)
    .limit(2)
    .toList();
console.log('RESULTS', res);
```

Results:

```
RESULTS [
  Map {
    Map { 'name' => 'Dimuthu', 'age' => 30 } => 2,
    Map { 'name' => 'Kamal', 'age' => 25 } => 1,
    Map { 'name' => 'Amal', 'age' => 34 } => 1,
    Map { 'name' => 'Dhanushka', 'age' => 40 } => 1,
    Map { 'name' => 'Sunimal', 'age' => 28 } => 1
  }
]
```

Though I limit query to 2 it is not working. It resulted all nodes.

Comment: I've another extension of this question, How are you reading individual values, i.e., how to reach 'name' of first element of Map. not able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `groupCount` step you have essentially created a single map structure. So the `limit(2)` does nothing as that map is considered one entity. If you add an `unfold()` before the `limit(2)` you should get just two results. Bear in mind if the map created by `groupCount` has the potential to become large you may want to consider ways to filter the results sooner. As an alternative you can give the `limit` step local scope using `limit(local,2)`.

Comment: Thank you! Both of your solutions are working fine. Can you advice me the performance optimized solution? I understood your concern. `groupCount` has potential to create large map if I have large set of data. Is there any alternative to avoid this issue?

Comment: One optimization could be to just group count initially using the vertices and not their value maps. Then only project out the value maps for the top two.

Comment: I tried `const res = await g.V().has('user', 'name', 'Waruna').as('u')
.out('like').in_('like')
.where(P.neq('u'))
.groupCount()
.order(gremlin.process.scope.local)
.by(gremlin.process.column.values, gremlin.process.order.desc)
.limit(gremlin.process.scope.local, 2)
.toList();`. But it gives only vertices map. How could I get it values?

Comment: if "groupCount()" return empty map and you try order by ".order(gremlin.process.scope.local) .by(gremlin.process.column.values, gremlin.process.order.desc)" is it crashing for you?

Comment: I would open a new question with your specific issue.